# Perl - How to solve the trouble with encoding in windows console?

Tags: perl, encoding

Trying to use russian lettaz and console acts like a donkey, because does not react on **use utf8/utf-8 or cp1251 directives**.
What the encoding of the text marked by red colour I don't know.
Anybody knows how to solve that ? Code listing below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::IxHash;

tie my %hash, "Tie::IxHash";
   %hash = (
    'шляпа' => 'серая',
    'водка' => 'горькая',
    'вобла' => 'вкусная');

print "В упорядоченной вставке список хеша такой:\n";
foreach my $qwerty (keys %hash){
    print " $qwerty\n";
}
print "Кроме того, предметы обладают некоторыми свойствами:\n";
while((my($predmet, $opredelenie)) = each %hash){
print "$predmet $opredelenie","\n";
}
```

Comment: Solved the problem.
In the windows console we have cp866 codepage so even ANSI (cp1251) encoding looks incorrect.
Re-incoding the file from UTF8 to CP1251 helped to solve the problem.

What I did:

1) chcp 1251 in console.
2) Save file in ANSI encoding.

Now I need the way to do the same with UTF-8 encoding, but how... chcp does not support utf-8.
The last I need to do is to save changes in windows registry

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify STDOUT encoding. This script is utf-8 encoded:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#use Tie::IxHash;
use utf8;
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(cp866)";

my %hash = (
    'шляпа' => 'серая',
    'водка' => 'горькая',
    'вобла' => 'вкусная'
);

print "В упорядоченной вставке список хеша такой:\n";
foreach my $qwerty ( keys %hash ) {
    print " $qwerty\n";
}
print "Кроме того, предметы обладают некоторыми свойствами:\n";
while ( ( my ( $predmet, $opredelenie ) ) = each %hash ) {
    print "$predmet $opredelenie", "\n";
}
```